# How to call upon another class.java file as an object to add to a JPanel

Tags: java, class, oop, inheritance, jpanel

I have an assignment to create a smiley face graphic in one class using the paint method (simple enough) and using a button make it appear in 9 different panels on the main class. I understand the button and the painting of the smiley face just fine, but I can't seem to find a clear answer on what the best approach to getting the object created in the 2nd class brought into the JPanel on the 1st class.

The code is pretty rough right now, but I feel I have everything laid out correctly with my tables, I just don't know how to call upon the 2nd class's paint method.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SmileyGrid extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SmileyGrid myGrid = new SmileyGrid();
    myGrid.setSize(800, 800);
    myGrid.createGUI();
    myGrid.setVisible(true);
}

public SmileyGrid()
{


}

private void createGUI()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container window = getContentPane();

    //3x3 layout for smileys
    GridLayout smileLayout = new GridLayout(3,3);

    //Parent panel for smileys
    JPanel panelSmiley = new JPanel ();


    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout (smileLayout);
        mainPanel.add(panelSmiley);
        mainPanel.add(panelSmiley);
        mainPanel.add(panelSmiley);
        mainPanel.add(panelSmiley);
        mainPanel.add(panelSmiley);
        mainPanel.add(panelSmiley);
        mainPanel.add(panelSmiley);
        mainPanel.add(panelSmiley);
        mainPanel.add(panelSmiley);




}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that all you need to do is introduce a class that extends JPanel and implement its paintComponent method. Then add a new instance of this class to each section of the grid. (I think if you instantiate it once then add the same reference multiple times you might have some issues)

```
public class Smiley extends JPanel {
    paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

This works because when a container (such as the contentPane you got) is painted it calls its children's paintComponent method as well. So you should be able to add this custom JPanel to the grid as you wrote above and whatever paint operations occur in the paintComponent will happen!

Also you should probably add the mainPanel to your window or else it won't be displayed.

Comment: I need to have the second class be a separate java file though, not just an added class to the same file.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue, you should be able to use the class from another file with no issue as long as both files are in the same package :)